# mobile app development (android and ios) with Star Micronics SDK

Tags: android, ios, mobile, printing, kivy

My boss just ask me to figure out which programming languages are best for developing mobile application for **Android and iOS devices**, which will use **Star Micronics' SDK** for printers.
I am best in Python but am okay with learning something new if needed.

Does anybody know how well do Kivy, Pyjnius and PyObjC support such SDKs?
Is this well supported or would you suggest any other solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Impossible to offer any suggestions without knowing full scope of your app, but going native generally has the least limitations.

Comment: It's probably possible to use pyjnius and pyobjus for this, but would likely require some manual configuration of kivy's toolchain (though I could be wrong here) and experimentation of your own. I'm not aware of anyone else having done it.